# JBoss Wildfly 9, JNDI exception

Tags: java, jboss, jndi, wildfly

I am new to JBoss Wildfly. I have used JBoss 7.1.1 and it was working fine with the same Database with same changes. I have changed standalone.xml file to connect to the Server Database in wildfly JBoss. But whenever I tried to run standalone.bat file it is giving following error:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
("subsystem" => "datasources"),
("jdbc-driver" => "com.mysql")
]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0041: Failed to load module for driver [com.mysql]"
```

Have placed mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar under modules->com->mysql->main

The module.xml file is:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

The datasource in standalone.xml is as follows:

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/MySqlDS" pool-name="MySqlDS_Pool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</connection-url>
                <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                <driver>com.mysql</driver>
                <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>root</user-name>
                    <password>root</password>
                </security>
                <statement>
                    <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                    <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
                </statement>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql">
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: strange, it looks correct to me. Maybe a name collision? Can you please try using `<driver>mysql</driver>` in the datasource and change the driver definition to `<driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what version of WildFly you are using.
It looks like it isn't finding the module at all.

In WildFly 8+ you need to put it in the directory
/modules/system/layers/base/com/mysql/main/module.xml

Is this where you have it?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, there is a problem with the latest mysql jdbc driver has reported [here](https://developer.jboss.org/message/866635)

To workaround the issue you should specify the driver class in your standalone.xml:

```
<datasource
...
<driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
...
</datasource>
```

Comment: Already used this in standalone.xml file you can see in my question.